# SQLITE Trigger to update data that uses a foreign key

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, triggers, foreign-keys

I am trying to create a trigger in Sqlite that will allow users to edit a column, which will copy the previous row as a new entry and change any data that relied on the previous entry. These are the relevant tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "Menu" 
("ProductID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
"Description" VARCHAR, "Code" VARCHAR, "Price_Pence" INTEGER)

CREATE TABLE "OrderItems" 
("OrderItemsID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , 
"ProductID" INTEGER, "Quantity" INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(ProductID) REFERENCES Menu (ProductID))
```

Menu stores data such as:

```
ProductID | Description     | Code | Price_Pence
----------------------------------------------
1         | Egg Salad       |  ESL |     200
2         | Ham Salad       |  HSL |     200
3         | Cheese Sandwich |  CSD |     150

etc.
```

OrderItems stores data like:

```
OrderItemsID | ProductID | Quantity
------------------------------------
1            | 3         | 1
2            | 2         | 1

etc.
```

I was hoping to have it where I could change the price of a Product e.g. if i wanted Cheese Sandwich = 200, i could update that. If I Did that previous orders would now have the incorrect price, so I need to have a trigger that will insert a new row into Menu which will automatically give the row a new ProductID so in this case it would become:

```
ProductID | Description     | Code | Price_Pence
----------------------------------------------
1         | Egg Salad       |  ESL |     200
2         | Ham Salad       |  HSL |     200
3         | Cheese Sandwich |  CSD |     200
4         | Cheese Sandwich |  CSD |     150
```

This would then need to change any previous entries in OrderItems e.g.

```
OrderItemsID | ProductID | Quantity
------------------------------------
1            | 4         | 1
2            | 2         | 1
```

Currently I have this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "menuArchive"
BEFORE UPDATE OF Price_Pence ON Menu  

BEGIN 
INSERT INTO Menu 
(Description, Code, Price_Pence)
VALUES (old.Description, old.Code, old.Price_Pence)
;END
```

This inserts the new entry into Menu that I needed. However, I am unsure the best way to update the ProductID in OrderItems without it changing the productID for every order.

Comment: You can filter rows with WHERE.

Comment: @CL. 
I tried using a WHERE however, was unsure how I would insert the new ProductID into OrderItems table as the trigger is a BEFORE UPDATE trigger. Surely you would need to use a AFTER INSERT or something for it to see the new ProductID?

Comment: The trigger already knows the new values of the row to be updated.

Comment: @CL. Yes, However, if i use something like ProductID = new.ProductID the number that appears will still be the old one. I am not sure if this is due to the autoincrement. If not how would be the best way to actually get the new number in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new product ID value is the value that got assigned in the newly inserted row. In SQL, you can read it with the [last_insert_rowid() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid):

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Menu ...;    

  UPDATE OrderItems
  SET ProductID = last_insert_rowid()
  WHERE ProductID = OLD.ProductID;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly, I wasnt aware of the last_insert_rowid() function.